# in wordpress how to add to attribute(s) to an existing shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, function, attributes, shortcode

Here is example shortcode:

```
add_shortcode("sc_one","test_fn");

    function test_fn(){
       $attr = array('one'=>1,'two'=>2,'three'=>3);
       echo "attribute 1: ".$attr['one'] ." attribute 2: ".$attr['two']." attribute 3: ".$attr["three"];
    }
```

And here is the function where I'd like to add attributes to shortcode "sc_one"

```
function add_to_sc_one(){
     $more_attributes = array("four"=>4,"five"=>5);
   // code to add attributes to "sc_one" shortcode.
}
```

I"m just curious if its possible to modify an existing shortcode?

Comment: why dont u add in `test_fn()`; instead of creating new function

Comment: I"m just curious is there a way to add to an existing shortcode?  because i don't want to alter the original shortcode code for other reasons.

Comment: use `array_push()` function

Comment: the $attr array in the "test_fn" function is local to the function...so thats not possible outside the function...and like i said i don't want to change the original shortcode function/code, i simply want to add to it...

Comment: in essence i simply want to modify an existing shortcode(its attributes, content), without having to change the original shortcode's code...makes sense?